# In Flex, how do I create a CheckBox that can't be un-checked?

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox

In Flex, how do I create a CheckBox that can't be un-checked? I run a function when the checkbox is clicked. If that function encounters an error, I want the state of the checkbox to remain the same. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `enabled` attribute to prevent the checkbox from being accessed once it's in the state you mentioned.

```
onFunctionError():void {
    yourCheckbox.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: +1: N.B. You can also change the checked state of the checkbox programatically even while the checkbox is disabled.